# Basic MySQL help? - submitting data

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've been getting better at PHP - but I have NO idea what I'm doing when it comes to MySQL.

I have a code

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/test.php?for=abcde&affi=12345&reff=foo"><IMG></a>
```

I need to grab the "for", "affi" and "reff" and input them into a database

```
//Start the DB Call
    $mysqli = mysqli_init();

//Log in to the DB
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die('mysqli_init failed');
    }

    if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')) {
        die('Setting MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND failed');
    }

    if (!$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5)) {
        die('Setting MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT failed');
    }

    if (!$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE')) {
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

That's what I'm using to create a connection. It works. I've also got a table created, call it "table", with rows for "for", "affi", and "reff".

So my question is... someone gets directed to http://www.example.com/test.php?for=abcde&affi=12345&reff=foo

Now that I've got a DB connection open - how do I SEND that data to the DB before redirecting them to their destination site? They click - pass across this page - get redirected to destination.

**BONUS KARMA** - I also need a separate PHP file that I can create that PULLS from that data base. If you could point me at some instructions or show me a simple "how to pull this rows values from this table" I would be greatly appreciative :)

Comment: Make sure you understand [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Idempotent_methods_and_web_applications); GET should (usually) not cause an insert like this (logging pagehits etc. aside, so you **might** be correct in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'll want to use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to get the URL parameters.

Then you want to run an [insert query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) on the db with the values you got, which should be something like:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(x, y, z)
```

Then you need to change the page using a [location header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

For the bonus question you just need the code you have now with a select query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1;
```

and then fetch the [query results](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

If this does not answer your questions please provide some clarifications.

Comment: The other answer is good, providing me with a best practices approach - however this seems to answer my actual questions! Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli is the deprecated function and now PDO is recommended to connect to database. You could do following.

```
<?php
  $conn = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Read more [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: I appreciate the PDO info. I did some research and it seems MySQLi vs PDO is negligible for me - though I will probably change to PDO since a) I'm not very far into this project yet, and b) it seems like the current best practice. Thanks

Comment: @AlexDemchak The biggest reason to use POD is it doesnt depend upon particular database. mysqli only works with mysql database, and in future if you need to change your database to something else(lets say sqlite) the whole code will break(or at lease need to change in lots of places).